# Join table A of IDs on either of 2 columns in table B, return the value in the unmatched column

Tags: sql, presto

Edit: In the preview the tables look perfectly fine but I'm not sure why the tables in my final published question look off

I'd like to join together two tables, as shown below on A.id = B.source_id OR A.id = B.target_id into a new table C

The resulting table C should have the columns A.id, and either B.source_id or B.target_id - whichever was the unmatched column value. What would be an easy way to do that?

I've considered just duplicating table B but inverting source_id and target_id, then matching on just one of the columns but with large datasets (hundreds of millions of rows) that seems a bit impractical.

Would love your thoughts!

```
Table A
| id |
| ----|
| 123 |
| 456 |
| 789 |

Table B
| source_id | target_id | ... | 
| ----------| --------- | ---- |
| 123       | 111       | misc |
| 222       | 456       | misc |
| 333       | 789       | misc |

Result: Table C
| A.id | new_id_column | ... | 
| ---- | ------------- | ---- |
| 123  | 111           | misc |
| 456  | 222           | misc |
| 789  | 333           | misc |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverting the table is a good idea.  But you can also use two `left join`s and `coalesce()` logic:

```
select a.id,
       coalesce(bs.target_id, bt.source_id),
       coaesce(bs.col1, bt.col1)
from a left join
     b bs
     on a.id = bs.source_id left join
     b bt
     on a.id = bt.target_id
```

Comment: Wow very elegant... thank you! Do you have a sense of which is more efficient performance wise? I'm talking a database of hundreds of millions of rows for 'Table B' potentially

Comment: @PythonLearner . . . In most databases, I think this would be pretty efficient because the joins can be optimized.  Of course, it is worth testing on your data on your system.